# Are there placeholders for attributes of a struct? (C)

Tags: c, struct, cs50, placeholder

I'm trying my hand at CS50's Filter and I'm at the blurring of pixels part. I'm able to access colors of a pixel with

```
image[row][pixel].rgbtRed
image[row][pixel].rgbtGreen
image[row][pixel].rgbtBlue
```

I want to be able to call a function that calculations the average of the surrounding pixels and pass in the color that I want the average of. Is there some sort of placeholder so that I can access a particular element/attribute of the struct? (Not sure of the proper name of it sorry).

I'm still very new and tried putting it between brackets and so on but nothing worked.

Here's the function where I try to get the value of the passed on color.

```
float calcAverage(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pixel, string color)
{
    float sum =  image[row][pixel].color + image[row][pixel - 1].color; 
    return 0;
}
```

And this is how I call the function.

```
redAverage = calcAverage(height, width, image, row, pixel, "rgbtRed");
```

Right now my .color plan doesn't work because know he's looking for an attribute called color. This is the error I get

```
error: no member named 'color' in 'RGBTRIPLE'
float sum =  image[row][pixel].color + image[row][pixel - 1].color;
```

I kept the sum short for testing purposes. Thanks in advance, I'm starting to think this isn't possible and I should leave it. Once again sorry if I use the wrong terminology for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Btw, wouldn't you rather have your function return `sum`  instead of 0, or do some more calculations (division by 2)?  As it stands the function doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @NateEldredge OP wants to do the equivalent of an `eval` or macro.

Comment: Oh now I see - I missed that `color` was an argument to the function.  Right, no reflection in C.  I guess there is `offsetof` but I'm not going to recommend that to a beginner either.

Comment: @NateEldredge oh yeah of course, I just set it to return 0 for testing purposes because i want to make it through compiling first haha

Comment: Since C doesn't have any kind of [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) it's not possible. You have to parse the string yourself and then get the value from the corresponding member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a string variable as a substitute for a member name.  You would need to check the string's value and select the field based on that.

```
float calcAverage(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], 
                  int row, int pixel, string color)
{
    if (!strcmp(color, "rgbtRed")) {
        return image[row][pixel].rgbtRed + image[row][pixel - 1].rgbtRed;
    } else if (!strcmp(color, "rgbtGreen")) {
        return image[row][pixel].rgbtGreen + image[row][pixel - 1].rgbtGreen;
    } else if (!strcmp(color, "rgbtBlue")) {
        return image[row][pixel].rgbtBlue + image[row][pixel - 1].rgbtBlue;
    } else {
        // invalid color
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via offsets to the members, as demonstrated in the code below. In one sense, using this is somewhat kludgey. However, it may be useful and appropriate in some situations. Because explicit conversions are used, overriding common compiler warnings about types, care must be exercised.

```
typedef struct { float red, green, blue; } RGBTRIPLE;


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>


/*  Get the offset of a member in an RGBTRIPLE using the C standard "offsetof"
    feature.  This could be a function, preferably a static inline function
    visible where it is used.
*/
#define OffsetOf(member)    (offsetof(RGBTRIPLE, member))

/*  Get a member of an RGBTRIPLE by its offset.

    This uses the offset to locate the member and then converts the address to
    a pointer to the member type, which we then use with "*" to refer to the
    member.  That produces an lvalue for the member which can be used to read
    (use the value of) or write (assign to) the member.

    This must be a macro because a function cannot return an lvalue.
*/
#define MemberByOffset(Structure, Offset) \
    (*(float *)((char *) &Structure + Offset))


static float Average(RGBTRIPLE *Array, size_t Offset)
{
    static const size_t N = 2;  // For demonstration only.

    float sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        sum += MemberByOffset(Array[i], Offset);

    return sum/N;
}


int main(void)
{
    RGBTRIPLE Array[] = {{ 10, 20, 30 }, { 100, 200, 300 }};
    printf("Red average = %g.\n",   Average(Array, OffsetOf(red  )));
    printf("Green average = %g.\n", Average(Array, OffsetOf(green)));
    printf("Blue average = %g.\n",  Average(Array, OffsetOf(blue )));
}
```